# How Do I Unroll a Variadic Template in a Condition?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, index-sequence

I'm looking to unroll a variadic template into separate functions used in the conjunction of an `if`-statement. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename T, size_t I>
bool bar(const T& param) { return param[I] != 13; }

template <typename T, size_t... ARGS>
void bar(const T& param, const std::index_sequence<ARGS...>&) { 
    if(bar<ARGS>(param) && ...)
    {
        cout << "no matches\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "matched\n";
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error:

> error C3520: `ARGS`: parameter pack must be expanded in this context

I want the line: `if(bar<ARGS>(param) && ...)` to unroll to: `if(bar<0U>(param) && bar<1U>(param) && bar<2U>(param))` Is there a way I can do this? Or is there an additional adapter that I can use which will accomplish this?

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PnBWqa)

Comment: Use a compiler that supports folding?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont So in the sad event that mine does not... Can I do anything?

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++17's [fold-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) you need to change two things to make it work:

1.Change the order of template parameters in `bar` so that `T` can be deduced when `I` in explicitly specified:

```
template <size_t I, typename T>
bool bar(const T& param) { return param[I] != 13; }
```

2.Add a pair of parentheses inside `if` since they are a mandatory part of a fold-expression:

```
if ((bar<ARGS>(param) && ...))
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/i7etLi)

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional couple of parentheses

```
// .V.......................V
if( (bar<ARGS>(param) && ...) )
```

Obviously if your compiler support C++17 (template folding).

Maybe clearer as follows

```
if( true == (bar<ARGS>(param) && ...) )
```

Answer (score 1):

> So in the sad event that mine does not *[support fold expressions]* ... Can I do anything?

Well, if that's really the case and the issue was not solely for [forgetting the required parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693115/1312382), then you can go the way variadic templates needed to be handled before C++17:

```
template < typename T >
bool bar(T const& param) { return true; }

template <typename T, size_t I, size_t ... II>
bool bar(T const& param) { return param[I] != 13 && bar<T, II...>(param); }

template <typename T, size_t... ARGS>
void bar(T const& param, std::index_sequence<ARGS...> const&)
{
    if(bar<T, ARGS...>(param))
    {
        std::cout << "no matches\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "matched\n";
    }
}
```